# почему остальные анимационные клипы "проигрываются" быстрее Чем первый клип по умолчанию При одних и тех же кадрах(samples)

Tags: unity3d, анимация

анимация "проигрывается" намного быстрее Чем надо Несмотря на то что тот же временной промежуток между кадрами Что и в первом клипе(где скорость анимации нормальная) И заметил такой нюанс
(это не столь важно Но странно Кроме первого клипа В других клипах масштаб не приближает шкалу-график времени настолько Насколько приближает первый клип)
[image: Walk_0]

[image: Walk_1]

Comment: А количество проигрываемых кадров в секунду одинаковое выставлено?

Comment: помимо кадров в секунду можно настроить скорость анимации. поизучайте инструмент, которым работаете.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Спасибо этим и занимаюсь

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Спасибо этим и занимаюсь

Answer (score 0):

Нажмите на вертикальное *троеточие* (в верхнем правом углу окна animation) -> **Show sample rate"**
появится поле samples рядом с плеером" Там скорректируйте колво samples